# ViewWillAppear not getting called with UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Background & Objective: I have a UISplitViewController based iPad app - till now it supported 4 orientations but now I want to lock it down to only landscape.
I changed `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` of the left view controller to support only landscape mode, but this stops its `viewWillAppear` from getting called.

Details: My iPad's view controllers are organized as below:

```
window
`-- splitVC (UISplitViewController)
    `-- rootNav (UINavigationController)
        `-- hvc (HostManagerViewController, derived from UIViewController)
    `-- detailViewController (DetailViewController, derived from UIViewController)
```

This is implemented in the App Delegate as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    HostManagerViewController *hvc  = [[[HostManagerViewController alloc]
                                       initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *rootNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                        initWithRootViewController:hvc] autorelease];
    UISplitViewController *splitVC= [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [splitVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,
                                 detailViewController, nil]];

    splitVC.delegate = detailViewController;
    [window addSubview:splitVC.view];
    [window setRootViewController:splitVC];
    return YES;
}
```

`viewWillAppear` gets called when both `DetailViewController.m` and `HostManagerViewController.m` contain

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
Console output:
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 3
Hostmanager: Viewdidload
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Hostmanager: viewwillappear
```

But when I change `HostManagerViewController`'s code to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```

then 'viewWillAppear` of HostManagerViewController is not invoked. Console output

```
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1 (1 is the numeric value of interfaceOrientation)
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 3
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 3
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 3
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 3
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 3
Hostmanager: Viewdidload
Should rotate called to hostmanager with 1
```

Only Landscape modes are supported in the Info.plist

EDIT: Inserted NSLog messages to track `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `viewWillAppear` and `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: is it possible for you to upload a sample of this project?

Comment: what iOS version are you running this on?

Comment: I am using 4.3. Reducing it to a smaller testcase can be done. Where do I upload it then?

Comment: have you tried the suggestion from my post? it is very possible that will solve your problem. You are setting the SplitViewController delegate to the detailviewcontroller and if this will return YES for the change of orientation then it will try to rotate all the controller residing inside SplitViewController and then your HostManagerViewController  will refuse to change the orientation (and this can be your problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked what iOS version you were using because I tried to create a simple reproduction of your problem and found the behavior differs between 4.3 and 5.0. It actually does make all the correct calls in 5.0. I believe this to simply be a bug with the UISplitviewController. Splitview controller was quite buggy. aopsfan's answer does not solve the problem (I have confirmed this). I would suggest subclassing uisplitviewcontroller, and overriding the splitview controller's viewwillappear, viewdidappear like so:

```
#import "testSplitViewController.h"

@implementation testSplitViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSString *reqSysVer = @"5.0";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
        [[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSString *reqSysVer = @"5.0";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
        [[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] viewDidAppear:animated];
}
@end
```

You have to check the version number so that you don't make the viewDidAppear call twice.

Or just go with 5.0 or above if you can, since the bug seems to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes! There seems to be a bug in split view controller - so forcing `viewWillAppear` on the children views from split view seems to be the workaround. Thanks much, @ACBurk

Comment: Is there a more generic way than version checks before calling `viewDidAppear`? There is `isViewLoaded`, but is there also a `hasViewAppeared` kind of a call?

Comment: Not that I know of off the top of my head, but I'll look into it

Comment: This may be a more general problem than just the UISplitViewController. I'm running into situations where viewDidAppear: (and viewWillAppear:) are not called on ordinary view controllers on an iOS-4 iPad, but these methods are called when running on an iOS-5 iPad.

Comment: And I seem to have a problem with it not even being called on iOS5 on the iPad. Go figure.

Comment: We're still seeing this issue with UISplitViewController in iOS 10. Solution of forwarding calls works great, though!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, since a `UISplitViewController` has two parts, you need a universal implementation of shouldAutorotate.  I suppose that tackling the rotation of the view controllers individually can cause some weird side affects--though please take note that I was not able to replicate your `viewWillAppear` issue, so this solution is really a guess.

I would recommend making a dead-simple subclass of `UISplitViewController`.  Name it "SplitViewController", and in it's `.m` file, delete everything except shouldAutorotate, which will look like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```

Now change your shouldAutorotate code in `HostManagerViewController` and `DetailViewController` back to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Now, in your app delegate, use this class instead of `UISplitViewController`. This should (may) fix your problem.

Comment: I also agree with aopsfan, you should not block this on each view controller, you should block it in the root controller (UISplitViewController in your case).

Comment: +1 Thanks for suggesting this. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You set the delegate of the UISplitViewControler to the detailViewController

```
splitVC.delegate = detailViewController;
```

I think the best place to block the rotations will be in the DetailViewController and not in the HostManagerViewController. I would change the - shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in the HostManagerViewController to return allways YES and in the DetailViewController i would add:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape == interfaceOrientation);
}
```