# iOS specific behavior when switching views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewwillappear

I'm seeing a weird problem related to subview methods getting called that appears to be iOS version specific.

I have two swappable views with parent view controller than determines which one will show. Basically there is a login view that gets swapped out to an account view when you log in and swaps back out to login when you log out.

The code is pretty straight forward. Here is a sample method from the parent view controller that gets called when you log in:

```
- (void) showAccountView:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.accountController == nil)
        self.accountController = [[[AccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccountViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [self.loginController viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.accountController viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.loginController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:alertsController.view atIndex:0];

    [self.loginController viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.accountController viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

There is another one just like this for showing the login view. Pretty straightforward. The problem that I'm having is that the viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear methods are all getting called once under iOS 4.3 but twice under iOS 5.0 and 5.1.

For example, in all iOS versions, the subview's viewWillAppear gets called when the parent view directly calls it (of course). However, only iOS 5.0 and 5.1 does it it get called a second time during the call to insertSubview.

So, if I remove everything except the calls to removeFromSuperview and insertSubview, so it looks like this:

```
- (void) showAccountView:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.accountController == nil)
        self.accountController = [[[AccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccountViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [self.loginController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:alertsController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

Now under 5.0 and 5.1 the subview methods only get called once each during insertSubview. However, it causes a problem under 4.3 because they don't get called at all.

I've read several posts related to making sure that the subview methods are called, but I haven't seen anything quite like this where the behavior is iOS dependent.

Also the only way I can think to make this work is to check the iOS version at runtime and call the subview methods directly for iOS 4.3 and not call them under 5.0 and 5.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: First off, you should never have to call `viewWill/Did`... Second, how do you know they aren't being called?

Comment: I agree with you that I should't have to call them but apparently I do because they're not getting called on their own in 4.3. I can tell they're not being called because the breakpoints I have set aren't being hit. Also, it's obvious from the functionality of the view that they're not being called. Actually, I just found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890374/viewwillappear-not-getting-called-with-uisplitviewcontroller) that discusses a similar issue to the one I'm seeing in the answer. They appear to assume it's a bug in iOS and recommend using a dynamic version check.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to have one view controller's content inside another view controller EXCEPT with the new parent/child view controller support that was added in iOS 5. It's now officially supported using a number of new methods (e.g. addChildViewController, transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion)

If you do try to host one view controller's view inside another under iOS 4 or earlier, you are fighting against the OS every step of the way.

Comment: I got this technique out of an iOS development book, not that it makes it right. So what would be the appropriate way to achieve what I'm doing with a version of iOS earlier than 5.0?

Comment: @Duncan C I understand that there are restrictions on some ViewControllers, e.g. a UISplitViewController must be the root. However, it's quite common to put a UITableViewController in a UISplitViewController. Please could you clarify your point, or point us at the documentation that supports it? Thanks.

Comment: @strips, I meant that before iOS 5 you're not supposed to put one of YOUR custom view controller's content inside another. Apple's container view controllers (navigation controller, tab bar controller, and on iPad, split view controller) are special, and designed to contain other view controllers. 

The parent/child view controller scheme built into iOS 5 lets you create your own container view controllers that have different behaviors. 

I did some digging and couldn't find the statement in the docs that you should not have one view controller's view inside anthers pre iOS 5 but I've seen it.